# how to detect click on button, video element in webview?

Tags: android, webview, touch

i can detect some events (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html#constants) in html using WebView.HitTestResult on webview.onTouch event. what i try to achieve is that when user click anywhere in webivew, if it does not start any action like play/pause video, redirect some page etc then toggle visibility of footer linearLayout in same activity. but i can't catch some actions like click on button, play/pause button of video element in webview. So how i can i detect these actions?

```
   webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView) v).getHitTestResult();

            if (hr != null) {
                Log.w("webView.onTouch", "getExtra = " + hr.getExtra() + "\t\t Type=" + hr.getType());
            } else {
                Log.w("webView.onTouch", event.toString());
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Atleast Get the Element Name or Id or class or any attribute to set onClick attribute if You know It Then It's really easy use Javascript to addattribute for onClick

```
Webview webview;
.....
```

Your code or whatever
  ...
        webview.addJavascriptInterface(new javasctiptinterface(),"javasciptinterfaceCall");

```
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('Element_NameAttribute_Value')[0].setAttribute('onClick','javascriptinterfaceCall.clicked()');");




        }
   });


    Class javasctiptinterface{
@javascriptinterface
public void clicked(){
... Your Code ......
}
```

Comment: thank you but the app is kind of book reading so i have ~200 html page contains diferrence content. so i cannot apply this solution for my case.

Comment: Maybe You can Apply... Just A Suggestion :- If You Don't Know Element Attribute Name... Then You can check its Pattern like which class or which Element is Basically Showing it... And Once You get that may be There is some class or anything which will be similar for sure and What You can do is That Take The Whole Page Html By  calling :- "document.body.innerHTMl" into a javascript function.and It its source just simply search for that className or Whatever and then get Your Required Element's ClassName and then invoke the onClick javascript for it.